# Distorted displacement on UV Sphere

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, displacement

So i'm following CGMatter's tutorial on procedural lava, but when I put the displacement on the sphere, the top is weirdly twisted, and also the rest of the displacement is pointed in one direction, not uniform. I have adaptive subduvisions enabled for the sphere.
[image]

Comment: plug the color output into the vector instead of the factor output.

Comment: The same twisting effect occurs with color.

Comment: UV sphere might not be the best shape to try this on, as it has two poles at the top and bottom, connected to triangles. Try to use a quad based primitive like a cube with a subsurf modifier.

Comment: Yes, or a subdivided cube, and it should work better in object space rather than tangent space. The color output should fix the displacement going only in one direction though.